# Symfony 2 SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused Error

Tags: symfony, pdo, doctrine, dbal

I get an error like database operations using Symfony2.

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused
```

parameters.yml

```
parameters:
  database_driver: pdo_mysql
  database_host: 127.0.0.1
  database_port: '8889'
  database_name: symfony
  database_user: root
  database_password: root
  mailer_transport: smtp
  mailer_host: 127.0.0.1
  mailer_user: null
  mailer_password: null
  locale: tr
  secret: ef9b4381fe75208f060b7c786951242bebcfb3c2
  database_path: /private/var/mysql/mysql.sock
```

And console:

```
Kemal-Karakass-MacBook-Pro:~ kemalkarakas$ locate mysql.sock
/private/var/mysql/mysql.sock
```

How do I resolve the error?

Comment: Are you sure that you can connect to MySQL on `127.0.0.1:8889` with username/password `root:root` ? The default MySQL port `3306` btw.

Comment: Yes I'm sure try{
 $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=symfony; port=8889', 'root','root');
}catch (PDOException $e){
 echo $e->getMessage();
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM Pages";
foreach ($conn->query($sql) as $row)
{
    echo $row['name'].'<br />';
} it's working

Comment: try to comment out the `database_path` directive - do you want to connect through `127.0.0.1:8889` or the socket? If you want to use the socket - did you configure MySQL to use this socket location and tried connecting through it aswell?

Comment: ... and remove the single quotes `'` around your port :)

Comment: database path: null     I tried did not work in the form of

Comment: did you remove the single quotes? either ommit them completely or use double-quotes to enter a string in YAML.

Comment: I have tried without the quotes problem continues

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is a parameter **unix_socket** you can use within your config.yml.

See full configuration example:

```
# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection: default
        connections:
            default:
                driver:   %database_driver%
                dbname:   %database_name%
                user:     %database_user%
                host:     %database_host%
                password: %database_password%
                unix_socket: /tmp/mysql.sock
```

Comment: As stated in the comments above he wants to connect through ip:port not through a socket but this might definitely help others :)

Answer (score 40):

i had the same issue and fixed it changing

```
database_host: 127.0.0.1
```

to

```
database_host: localhost
```

in parameters.yml

hopefully this helps

Comment: In later versions of Symfony this may also be in your .env file, specifically the DATABASE_URL

Answer (score 16):

On **Mac OSX** using **Mamp Pro**, what solved the problem for me was going to the **MySQL** tab on the UI and checking the option **Allow network access to MySQL**

Don't forget to click **Save** to update the settings

[image]

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem using **MAMP** because the default port is not `3306` but `8889`.

You can find that information in the MAMP starting web page.

**My parameters**

```
parameters:
    database_driver: pdo_mysql
    database_host: 127.0.0.1
    database_port: '8889'
    database_name: symfony_blog
    database_user: root
    database_password: root
    mailer_transport: smtp
    mailer_host: 127.0.0.1
    mailer_user: null
    mailer_password: null
    locale: en
    secret: 7f03537e81f981683bc773b9ec7113ab5861adec
    database_path: null
```

Comment: I'm using OSX and I just started mysql in Terminal then entered `SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_name = 'port';`. Port number was 8889, I entered it in parameters.yml and connection finaly made.

Answer (score 5):

This is a bit stupid but I arrived on this post googling the same error, so maybe this can help someone.

In case you have this Connection refused Error double check that your database is up and running, in my case I simply forgot to power on MAMP...

Answer (score 3):

Had this issue "SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory" on symfony 3.2.9 on deployment

I fixed it by changing the database_host value from "localhost" to my server IP on my parameters.yml file

but I had this another error message when trying to run commandline by SSH:

```
[Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\ConnectionException]
  An exception occured in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused
```

I finaly fix it by adding these 2 lines on my config.yml file in Doctrine configuration section :

```
unix_socket: /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
server_version: '5.5'
```

all my final doctrine configuration is like this:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver: pdo_mysql
        host: '%database_host%'
        port: '%database_port%'
        dbname: '%database_name%'
        user: '%database_user%'
        password: '%database_password%'
        unix_socket: /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
        server_version: '5.5'
        charset: UTF8
```

hopefully this helps

Answer (score 2):

After seeing the answers and playing around with this myself I figured out the problem:

The default installation of LAMPP, MAMPP has the following in the my.cnf file:

`skip-networking`

This means that mysql will not listen on TCP/IP so you can tell doctrine to try any port in the 64K and it won't do any good until you comment out the directive above and get mysql to listen to TCP/IP ports.

Please ensure you restart LAMPP, MAMPP or reload mysql after commenting out the `skip-networking` directive.

Answer (score 2):

If anyone is still stuck on this issue when using a **virtual environment**, I found if you are attempting to run database commands on the host machine and running into the `"connection refused"` error, try **ssh-ing into your guest machine** and running the commands directly so the path to mysql.sock is correct.

(I guess it makes sense that the relative path needs to be on the virtual guest machine, not the host machine).

Answer (score 1):

### Configuring symfony2/doctrine to connect to MySQL using host:port

- comment out `doctrine.dbal.path: %database_path%` in `app/config/config.yml`
- remove/comment out the parameter `database_path` from `app/config/parameters.yml`
- check your configuration files for correct indentation
- wrap either none of the values in `app/config/parameters.yml` single quotes or put all in double quotes.

Afterwards your configuration should look like this:

**Parameters**

```
# app/config/parameters.yml

parameters:
    database_driver:   "pdo_mysql"
    database_host:     "127.0.0.1"
    database_port:     "8889"
    database_name:     "symfony"
    database_user:     "root"
    database_password: "root"

    # comment out or remove
    # database_path: ~
```

**Configuration**

```
# app/config/config.yml

# ...
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:   %database_driver%
        host:     %database_host%
        port:     %database_port%
        dbname:   %database_name%
        user:     %database_user%
        password: %database_password%
        charset:  UTF8

        # path is for pdo_sqlite: i.e. %kernel.root_dir%/data/data.db3
        # comment it out !
        # path:   ~
```

Answer (score 1):

Running on MAMP, this is what configuration of /app/config/parameters.yml that worked for me:

```
parameters:
    database_host: '127.0.0.1'
    database_port: '8889'
    database_name: test
    database_user: root
    database_password: root
```

I lost quite some time with `database_host: localhost`, which didn't work.

**Beginners Tips:**

Don't forget to remove the semicolon `;` to enable `extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll` in php.ini (in application/MAMP/conf/phpX.X.X - check your current version in MAMP settings)
and/or in php.ini and/or php.ini.default in Macintosh HD/private/etc (use spotlight search to find this hidden file).

Answer (score 1):

Today on a fresh installation of Symfony3 I had the same error:

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Permission denied

Installation specs:

- CentOS Linux 7.2.1511
- Symfony 3.1.2
- MariaDB 5.5.47
- PHP 7.0.8

An earlier answer by izus did resolve the problem on my server. He suggests to change the parameter `database_host` from `127.0.0.1` to `localhost` in the Symfony configuration file `app/config/parameters.yml`

The real origin of the problem was not inside Symfony configuration, but authorization inside the database server. I've created the database and authorization for this database by executing the following SQL queries:

```
CREATE DATABASE user CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON database.* TO user@localhost IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

This query implies only the host 'localhost' is authorized. This doesn't match '127.0.0.1' exactly. The database server rejects the incomming connection, and Symfony is throwing an exception and showing this error message.

Possible solutions to this specific situation:

1. Change the database_host parameter
2. Change the authorization inside the database server

Answer (score 1):

In MAMP PRO I have activated "Allow Network Access to mysql" and my "php artisan migrate" is working now for that special app.