# Switching from 'dev' to 'prod' : database connection error

Tags: symfony

I'm developing a web site with Symfony2.

I tried to switch from the 'dev' environment to 'prod'. But when I connect me with correct identifiers (in the database),  I have a database connection error : "SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused".

Whereas I don't have any error when I test this connection with the "dev" environment on the same server and with the same database.

What it can cause this error ?

Do you have an idea ?

Thank you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19629932/symfony-2-sqlstatehy000-2002-connection-refused-error

Comment: I already saw this post but nothing works.

My situation : 
Local server, dev : connection works; 
Local server, prod : connection works; 
Web server, dev : connection works; 
Web server, prod, connection doesn't work;

Comment: The only thing that can cause this is that there are differences in your connection settings. In which file have you defined the connection settings?

Comment: In the file parameters.yml :  
parameters:  
    database_host: host.com  
    database_port: port  
    database_name: name  
    database_user: user  
    database_password: password

Comment: And in the config.yml  : 
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:   "pdo_mysql"
        host:     "%database_host%"
        port:     "%database_port%"
        dbname:   "%database_name%"
        user:     "%database_user%"
        password: "%database_password%"
        charset:  UTF8
        unix_socket: /tmp/mysql.sock

Comment: Please share more details, and add all of them **to your question** by editing it

Answer (score 0):

8 years later, still have the same problem. The way to fix it is to specify a server_version in your config file (e.g doctrine.yaml)

```
server_version: '8.2.0'
```