# Error database connection in Symfony

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine, server

I am trying to connect my database with MySQL, but I have the following error:

> [Doctrine \ DBAL \ Exception \ ConnectionException]
>      An exception occured in driver: SQLSTATE [HY000] [2002] Connection refused

I have my project in the following path (I'm using OS X Capitan): `/Applications/ XAMPP/htdocs/Projects/Cupon`. I'm trying to complete the get and set methods automatically with the command: `php app/console doctrine:generate:entities TiendaBundle`.

Class code (Project/Cupon/src/Cupon/TiendaBundle/Entity/Tienda.php):

```
<?php

namespace Cupon\TiendaBundle\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
/** @ORM\Entity */

class Tienda
{

  /**
  * @ORM\Id
  * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
  * @ORM\GeneratedValue
  */
  protected $id;

  /** @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100) */
  protected $nombre;

  /** @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100) */
  protected $slug;

  /** @ORM\Column(type="string", length=10) */
  protected $login;

  /** @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255) */
  protected $password;

  /** @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255) */
  protected $salt;

  /** @ORM\Column(type="text") */
  protected $descripcion;

  /** @ORM\Column(type="text") */
  protected $direccion;

  /**
   * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Cupon\CiudadBundle\Entity\Ciudad")
   * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="ciudad_id", referencedColumnName="id")
   */
  protected $ciudad;

}
```

I have a database called "symfony" in MySQL (XAMPP 5.6.3) and my configuration file in Symfony is as follows:

```
parameters:
    database_driver: pdo_mysql
    database_host: 127.0.0.1
    database_port: null
    database_name: symfony
    database_user: root
    database_password: '123'
    mailer_transport: smtp
    mailer_host: 127.0.0.1
    mailer_user: null
    mailer_password: null
    locale: en
    secret: c11eccf2a788b331cb9548ff4106c7461
```

I don't know how I can connect my project Symfony with my database in phpmyadmin.

Comment: Are you sure your configuration file is ok? why are you using null for port property?

Comment: Alireza, I think so, I also used the port 3306, but I have the same problem, I've tried a thousand different ways but can not connect, you might help me a list of steps to make the connection phpmyadmin-symfony, thanks

Comment: Is the mysql service running? Did you try to replace 127.0.0.1 to localhost?

Comment: Iago, the service is running, If I change the port to localhost I have a different error: [Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\ConnectionException]                                
  An exception occured in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory

Comment: Try to set the unix_socket as in this tutorial: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19629932/symfony-2-sqlstatehy000-2002-connection-refused-error

Comment: Iago is saying "Did you test to replace 127.0.0.1 by localhost ?" He didn't speak about the port, but about the driver ;). Connect to mysql in console (or via phpmyadmin) and return us the result of this query : SHOW GRANTS FOR CURRENT_USER();

Comment: try clearing your cache `php app/console cache:clear` most of the times it's about caching.

Comment: @Juan Carlos HC Not sure if this makes a difference but in my parameters.yml file, the password is without quotes. You could also remove the reference to driver, that is not in my parameters either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope you have your problem already solved, if not my solution may help you.

I had a very similar problem, but I was using MAMP, I solved my problem changing the configuration of the `pdo_mysql.default_socket`
in the `/etc/php.ini`.

Why?
I used terminal to create the database with

> php app/console doctrine:database:create

and I use MAMP to test the site.

So, the problem, terminal was using a diferent `pdo_mysql.default_socket` than MAMP.

MAMP uses the config from

> /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/conf/php.ini

and terminal use the

> /etc/php.ini

My solution:

change in my `/etc/php.ini` the line

> pdo_mysql.default_socket=/var/mysql/mysql.sock

with:

> pdo_mysql.default_socket=/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock

Also I change my default zone:

> date.timezone = "Europe/Bucharest"

I hope, this could help you doing something simmilar but now using your XAMMP socket.

Sorry for my English.

Comment: Thanks this helped me, in my case I had to do sudo find / -name mysql.sock to find where it was for my xampp installation, then I followed your directions and it worked!  Some things to note is for some reason my php.ini file said it was located in /etc/ but was not, so I had to copy one there to get it to work.  Hope this helps someone.